# Migrating a project to PowerBuilder 2021 - getting "mixing array and non-array in assignment statement" error

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-conversion

I have migrated a project from PowerBuilder version *don't know* to PowerBuilder version 2021. While regenerating one the *windows* in one of the *libraries*; I get an error that says: "Mixing array and non-array in assignment statement". Tracing this error in the *open event* of the *window* takes me to this line(s):

1. parm = message.PowerObjectParm
   ...
2. parm.postevent("*some event*")
   and in the "clicked event" of a button I have this parameter used, too:
3. parm.triggerevent("*some event*")

in line one I get this error: "C0070: Mixing array and non-array in assignment statement."
line 2 this one: "C0068: Illegal use of array in expression"
and line 3 the same as #2: "C0068: Illegal use of array in expression"

Any help would be really appreciated since I'm using a paid library to convert *datawindows* to excel files(with keeping the format) and now this library is useless.

p.s. parm is a global variable in the *open event* of the same *window* with the type of *nonvisualobject*.

Comment: If you look at the PowerBuilder runtime libraries used with the "don't know" version they will give a version number as part of the name. i.e., pbvm120.dll indicating PB 12.0 version

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of this error

```
string ls_not_array
string ls_is_array[]

ls_is_array = ls_not_array
```

So somewhere in your scripts there is a method expecting an array and it's being sent a non-array (or vice versa) or some other type of assignment error exists.